# What doe 'Root Dispersion' mean? (w32tm /query /status)

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, w32time

I apologise for asking what seems like an easilly googlable question but I've tried, and even Microsoft's own article on W32tm doesn't seem to mention it.

I have recently been configuring time sync for a new DC on an existing domain (to replace an old DC holding the FSMO roles and set as the reliable time source)

On one member server I saw a Root Dispersion of about 4 seconds when running `w32tm /query /status` which concerns me slightly, so I want to find out what it means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy enough to find on Google.

Root dispersion is the maximum clock time difference that was ever observed between the local clock and the root clock.

Nothing to worry about.

Comment: the irony that "easy to google" is the first hit on google ...

Comment: That was ever observed? How would you explain then the root dispersion going down during multiple executions of the command `w32tm /query /status`